# Exclude dependency in all modules except one in Gradle

Tags: gradle

I have a dependency that I need removed from all modules of my application (10 modules), except for one.

In the top level build.gradle file, I have:

```
configurations.all { exclude group: 'com.nasty', module: 'nasty-dependency' }
```

Is there an easy way to express that for modules A thru I, I want to exclude this dependency, but in module J include it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head

```
[':A', ':B', ':C'].each {
   project(it).configurations.all { exclude group: 'com.nasty', module: 'nasty-dependency }
}
```

Or maybe

```
allprojects {
   if (path !=':X') {
      configurations.all { exclude group: 'com.nasty', module: 'nasty-dependency }
   } 
}
```